# How to fix issue of 'Undefined index: forwardto[] and implode(): Invalid arguments passed '

Tags: codeigniter

**first view page to forward**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <select name="forwardto[]" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <?php foreach($userlist as $row):?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['cid']?>">
                    <?php echo $row['FirstName'].$row['MiddleName'].$row['LastName']?>
                </option>
                <?php endforeach;?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

**Inside Controller**

```
function forward($param1='', $param2=''){
       $data1['message']='';
       $data['ForwarderId']=$this->session->userdata('cid');
       $data['ForwarderName']=$this->session->userdata('name');

       $data['Designation']=$this->session->userdata('position'); /* title ..I have created Designation in Stmessage table */

       $data1['RecieverId']=implode(', ', $_POST['forwardto']);
       $Rcid = implode(" ", $data1);
       $data['RecieverName']=$this->ag->name($Rcid);//this is not working
       //ag->is agency model

       $this->db->update('st_message', $data);
       if($this->db->affected_rows()>0){
          $dat['ReadStatus']='N';
          $this->db->where('Id', $param1);
          $this->db->update('st_message', $dat);
```

**Inside model**

```
public function name($Rcid)
   {
     $query=$this->db->query("SELECT CONCAT(e.FirstName, ' ',e.MiddleName, ' ', e. Lastname) as name, e.cid AS cid FROM bpas_user_profiles e
                             WHERE e.cid='".$Rcid."'");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
       return $query->row();              
    } else {
       return array();                
    }

}
```

Actually a data ,example 11112334 is selected and is  passed via forwardto[] to controller.
But when I pass this $Rcid which related to forwardto[] as parameter to the model, it is not able to fetch.Actually I want to  map number example 111323232 to  name and update it in the table

Comment: can you share here `$_POST['forwardto']`array?

Comment: Are you multi-selecting values with `<select name="forwardto[]">`?